# SQL Like Query in visual studio

Tags: sql

I can get other queries to work but I can't get this query to work in Visual Studio
Assuming ConnectionString is declared outside this function

public DataTable GetDtSearch(string searchname)
        {

```
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE (file_name LIKE @searchname)";


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {

            try
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            catch { return dt; }

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(@searchname,"%"+ searchname+"%");
                using (MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        adp.Fill(dt);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }

                }

            }
            con.Close();
        }




        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: The string "can't get this query to work" is not a built-in error message in any IDE.

Comment: An empty catch block is not going to help you much, instead catch `SqlException` and see what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@searchname","%"+ searchname+"%");
```

Enclose the parameter name (first argument) in quotation marks.

P.S. I've upvoted your downvoted question, but the downvoter was right to do so -- you need to say what's happening -- an error message, or "no results are returned" or something more precise than "can't get this query to work".

P.P.S. Also, use the **AddWithValue** method, since Add(string, object) signature has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Put quotes around the search param. -
`SELECT * FROM table WHERE (file_name LIKE '@searchname')`

Comment: an empty datatable was returned

Comment: Try it directly in a query in Management Studio before you assume the code is wrong. `select * from table where field like '%contents%'` works for me :)